# System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to Enum in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, system.text.json

I am facing an issue that my third party API sends me response in string which I convert to enum but API adds space at the end of some values for example instead of "Some value 1" it comes like "Some value 1 "

So while deserializing it creates problem.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumMemberConverter))]
public enum SomeEnum
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Some value 1")]
    Valu1 = 1,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Some value 2"), ]
    Valu2 = 2,
}
```

How can I resolve this issue in .NET 6 ?

I am using System.Text.Json

My problem is not with custom name, its actually with value at the time of de serialization

Comment: Not supported. You would need your own converter. See also https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31081

Comment: I suggest that instead of using an enum, you use a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @Poul Bak so I have to write a convertor than for Dictionary ?

Comment: No, I meant replacing the enum in your code with a `Dictionary`. Then the keys can be `Valu1` etc, while value can be `Some value 1` etc. Dictionarys are supported by `JsonSerializer`.